# one textview and one imageview inside a list view, how is it possible?

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I want to make code for a listview. In listview there will be a textview and an imageview both in one line of the listview. How is it possible. I am using that code in my TabHost control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own list view item layout, which includes a text view and an image view. Here's a good guide on  [writing a custom list view](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout that is specific to each line.  In your case, it will contain the textview and imageview wrapped in either a relative or linearlayout.   Then just inflate that view for each line